# ubuntu исходящее соединение для подключенного клиента

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, iptables

Перенес программу на новый сервер(ubuntu) установлена моя программа сервер, она обрабатывает входящие запросы и отправляет ответ клиенту. Входящие запросы проходят, я их вижу, а вот исходящие до клиента не доходят. Общение происходит по tcp сокету.
На другой машине работает, на винде
понимаю, что нужно что-то в iptables прописывать, но не догоняю что , INPUT и OUTPUT этот порт открыт, но видимо не все так просто, если ответ нужен по уже установленному соединению или я ошибаюсь?
iptables

```
root:# iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1111

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:1111
```

Была похожая ситуация на другому сервере, но там был предустановлен докер, и после того как программа была занесена в контейнер, а в настройках контейнера указал порт контейнера и локальный порт все заработало

Comment: у тебя же `policy ACCEPT` на всех цепочках... т.е. все пакеты и так разрешены...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я понимаю, но так не работает, поэтому начал пробовать дополнительные правила...

Comment: я к тому, что это значит, что проблема не в `iptables`... по крайней мере не на этом сервере... возвращает ли сокет ошибки? как ты определил, что ответы до клиента не доходят?

Comment: @Fat-Zer сокет ошибок не возвращает, у клиента возникает ошибка отсутсвия входящего соединения, так и определил

Comment: В убунте по умолчанию установлен файервол `ufw`. Попробуйте команду `sudo ufw allow <port>/tcp`

Comment: @PakUula я его отключил ufw disable прописал

Comment: @Drop, «*у клиента возникает ошибка отсутсвия входящего соединения*» — что именно ты под этим имеешь в виду? полузакрытое соединение о_О? тогда логику работы сервера стоит смотреть... а вообще я бы сниффером посмотрел бы, что на самом деле на клиетне и на сервере, что происходит...

Comment: @Fat-Zer обычное сокет соединение. Сервер слушает порт, клиент открывает новое соединение подключаясь по ип порт, отправляет запрос, после чего ожидает входящее соединение от сервера. 
Сервер принимает запрос , после чего открывает соединение к клиенту по входящим данным.

Comment: @Drop, что именно ты имеешь в виду под «входящим соединением»? ещё одно TCP-соединение? зачем? у тебя клиент, случаем, как это обычно бывает, не за NAT'ом?

Comment: @Fat-Zer   написано на  JAVA, как учился так и написал, запрос на сервер, ожидание ответа от сервера . в таком порядке. клиент у меня может быть любой пк или телефон, которые знают адрес сервера и подключаются к нему.

Comment: @Drop, нум... если я верно понял описание, то всё сделано через жопу и это хорошее время начать это переделывать ;)... если кратко, обычно клиент находится «за NAT'ом» (в простонародии — роутером) и для TCP сервер самостоятельно не может установить до него новое соединение, так что все подключения должны происходить со стороны клиента, а вообще всё взаимодействие следует делать в рамках одного соединения...

Comment: @Fat-Zer то что через жопу - очевидоюно же, начинающий самоучка)но до этого работала в конейнере докера и все хорошо было., так что думаю что все же что-то в ос надо мне настроить... то что за роутером - тоже верно

Comment: @Fat-Zer начал понемногу понимать, что нужно учесть что клиент не имеет реально ип. окей, голова уже кипит, куда хоть посмотреть ? не вкурсе? там просто этих правил миллион и nat ,forwarding а я на linux умею только баш скрипты запуск в скрине -_- :)

Comment: @Drop, посмотреть, в первую очередь, в сторону переписывания своего приложения... а если хочешь, чтоб хоть как-то заработало «как-есть» то в сторону проброски портов на своём роутере (если провайдр выдаёт тебе белый адрес).

Comment: @Fat-Zer на сколько я могу понимать в java такая специфика сокет соединений, однако все же, начал вызывать входящее соединение до закрытия исходящего и все заработало) спасибо за советы)

Comment: @Drop, ок.. получилось и хорошо... хотя я теперь ещё больше сомневаюсь, что ты имел в виду под «соединением», нудаладно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ох если бы я еще знал :D